# How to display animated images in android?

Tags: android

in my application  i want to display my own ads for that i want to dispaly my ads in image and it should be animated.So how to display animated images

Answer (score 5):

You can do frame-by-frame animations using an `AnimationDrawable` object.

Comment: please provide some sample code

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Answer (score 1):

i can help you in easy way.

first take **images** in which you want to show ads.if you want to show image as **admob** (google ads) then take image **320X50** resolution.

then create folder **anim** in res.

in **anim** create animation file like **anim1.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate android:fromXDelta="-300%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%" android:duration="1000" />
```

then create another file **anim2.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate android:fromXDelta="300%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%" android:duration="1000" />
```

use this file in image for animation. like

```
mAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.anim1);
mAnimation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.anim2);
```

here i use two images which change alternatively in some regular interval.for that i use **Timer**.

**new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new UpdateTimeTask(), 1, 10 * 1000);**

it call TimerTast class at fix schedule. here i call this class in every 10 second by (10 * 1000).
for that first create new class **UpdateTimerTast**

```
class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {
        // Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Timer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Message toMain = handler.obtainMessage();
        toMain.obj = "banner";
        handler.sendMessage(toMain);

    }
}
```

this class call Handler in which change and animate image in regular interval.

in Handler

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);

if (msg.obj.toString().contentEquals("banner")) {

            if (mBanner.isShown()) {
                mBanner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mBanner1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mBanner1.startAnimation(mAnimation1);

            } else if (mBanner1.isShown()) {
                mBanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mBanner.startAnimation(mAnimation);
                mBanner1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
```

Here mBanner1 and mBanner is ImageView.

that's it. done. :)

Comment: Please don't re-invent AnimationDrawable

Answer (score 0):

Best place to start is in the official guide about 2D graphics. Scroll down to the bottom where it talks about Tween animation and frame-by-frame. After that, Google around for animation tutorials. There are many very good ones out there.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by three ways:

- view animation
- frame by frame animation
- layout animation

best of luck

Comment: Try to avoid "u" and please use the post preview to see if your post looks like you want it to.