# Show animated image on Android

Tags: android

How do I show an animated image in Android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display animated images in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243335/how-to-display-animated-images-in-android) - third hit when I google for the exact same words in your title.

Answer (score 0):

For animated Image like AdMob (google Ads) check it. It will help you

[For Animation like AdMob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243335/how-to-display-animated-images-in-android?answertab=oldest#tab-top)