# How to make an image small rather than its original size?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an animation app in the android.
i have one big image in application.
The image should start from the center of screen. The image size will be bigger at the initial stage. While moving  to the left of the screen, its size should decrease(i.e. scaling should take place). Image should not go back to its original position. It should be placed at the leftside of the screen itself after the animation.

Can anyone please help.
Thanking you.

Comment: you mean you want to animate-resize it from center?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243335/how-to-display-animated-images-in-android

Comment: i want to make it smaller rather than its original size and it should be move towards backward while resizing

Comment: what do u mean by moving backward? it should be hidden?

Comment: it should move to back from its original position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand conrrectly you want to display an image and then animate it so that it appers to be reducing in size giving an affect that is going into the background.

You need to use ScaleAnimation
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html

A good tutorial regarding android animation can be found at:
http://www.hascode.com/2010/09/playing-around-with-the-android-animation-framework/#Scale_Animations

Comment: thanks Orlymee, it works. the image is scaling on the screen but now i want to stop the scaling of image at particular point how could i do this?